# Forward and Backward Euler method for a system of first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I was given the following second-order differential equation,
\begin{equation}y^{\prime\prime}+2y^{\prime}+y=g(t),\end{equation}
and that the solution is $y(t)=(1+t)(1+e^{-t})$. Using the solution I determined that
\begin{equation}g(t)=t+3.\end{equation}

Following from this I transformed this second-order differential equation into a system of first-order differential equations, which is
\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\y^{\prime}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\t+3\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
Now I want to perform a single step with $\Delta t=1$ starting from $t=0$ with the Forward Euler method and after that with the Backward Euler method. Firstly with the Forward Euler method I use:
\begin{equation}w_{n+1}=w_{n}+\Delta tf(t_{n},w_{n})\end{equation}
and I compute $w_{0}$ as
\begin{equation}w_{0}=\begin{pmatrix}y(0)\\y^{\prime}(0)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
so therefore
\begin{equation}w_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
Now I want to perform the Backward Euler method.
\begin{equation}w_{n+1}=w_{n}+\Delta tf(t_{n+1},w_{n+1})\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}w_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-2\end{pmatrix}w_{1}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
From which I get
\begin{equation}w_{1}=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}11\\3\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
y two results seems to be quite differnt and that gets me to believe that I have made a mistake somewhere. Could someone let me know if they believe this to be correct, or why this could be wrong?

Comment: I believe the backward method is iterative for each time step for it to converge.

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Here's some psuedocode: 
if abs( (y(i+1) - ynew)/ynew ) > 1e-14 then 
    ynew = y(i+1);
    y(i+1) = y(i)+h*f(x(i+1),ynew);
end

Comment: If I understand what you say correctly, then I believe that is the equation I used in my work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Equation is correct, but it must be evaluated multiple times to ensure it converges to an answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method

Comment: Alright thank you, but the questions asks me to perform one time step for the Forward and Backward method each and then compare each result. How would I be able to deduce an answer if the backward method needs multiple steps which the question does not ask for?

Comment: @macduff : It is possible, but not necessary to solve linear systems with iterative methods. If the ODE itself is non-linear, then the implicit method gives non-linear step equations to solve, which in most cases can only be done iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second is $(2.75, 0.75)^T$. Your results are not that different for a step size of $Δt=1$ and a Lipschitz constant $L$ between $2$ and $3$. This setup is on the border between barely useful and chaotic, you want $LΔt$ smaller $1.5$ for results that are qualitatively valid, and smaller $0.1$ for results that begin to be quantitatively valid.

If you want to get a better intuition of that, repeat the calculation with smaller step sizes $0.5, 0.25, 0.1$ (and the correspondingly increased step number) and observe that the error shrinks roughly linearly in the step size.